# How to fix AdapterError: Unexpected error from database adapter: object [{"_bsontype":"ObjectID","id":null}]

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo, objectid

I need to add ObjectId in nested collection in MongoDB, and i just upgrade my sails version, now when I'm going to update my collection and there is nested object have object id it's giving me below error

> AdapterError: Unexpected error from database adapter: object [{"_bsontype":"ObjectID","id":null}] is not a valid ObjectId

I tried mongo native query but it's not working.

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var data = {
      user: {
        id: ObjectID( '5b03ce2c0614084178992b83' ),
        name: "sumit",
      },
      _id: ObjectID('b9a38ab8936d83129ee55922')
};

let updatedMenu = await Db.update({ id: _id }).set(data).fetch().meta({
     skipRecordVerification : true,
     skipExpandingDefaultSelectClause : true,
     skipRecordVerification : true,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i experienced the same issue recently. I was working with sails and it has a hook of beforeCreate that is executed before the model document is created in its collection. 
In other words, it is the final function where you can make any modifications.
So as i know that one my addresses field has an account reference as mongodb object id. 
I simply converted it to string

e.g.

```
vendorStore.address.account = vendorStore.address.account.toString();
```

it never gave me any trouble afterwards.

If you have some issue in fetching it, perhaps you can convert at the time of retrieval.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

vendorStore.address.account = vendorStore.address.account.toString();

Comment: thanx for your reply